# Connection reset by peer - while reading response header from upstream using nginx and php-fpm7.2

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

**Below is the error log:**

nginx

> [error] 6518#6518: *1548 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.51.134.160, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/example HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

**php7.2-fpm.log**

> [error] 6518#6518: *1548 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.51.134.160, server: api.onsurity.com, request: "POST /api/example HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

**I have increased the timeout and size in nginx.conf**

```
client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 200M;
sendfile on;
send_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

**Another solution mentioned to increase the request time out and other limits in php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize=2000M
max_file_uploads=2000
memory_limit=128M
post_max_size=8000M
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

It is showing 502 gateway error while hitting the post request containing base64 image array. Approx. size would be 6MB

Answer (score 0):

If you've done all of the suggested configurations in Nginx and PHP-FPM and you are hosted in AWS, try increasing the **idle timeout** of the elastic load balancer which normally defaults to 60s.

[image: idle timeout]

More information here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/